# I can't go into windows after dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, windows-10

I am new trying dual boot and followed all instructions in a YouTube video to install ubuntu.

I installed ubuntu alongside Windows 10.
I do not take any Windows 10 recovery key backup.

Ubuntu got installed and Windows 10 is asking for a bitlocker key to boot.

In ubuntu, I can't access the wifi.

Now I cannot open Windows and also not able to use WiFi in ubuntu.
Please help me.

Comment: Okaaaaay...  Are you asking about getting into Windows or getting the WiFi working on Ubuntu?  The bitlocker question sounds like something more for [superuser](https://superuser.com/), and the WiFi question needs a good more detail before we can even begin to help you.  Please [edit] to clarify.  Thanks!